# Read from XML > Add to Listview

Tags: c#, linq, listview

I have some problems getting the data that i read from XML split into seperate columns. Any help this new C# coder would get would be appreciated.

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("emails.xml");            

        var t = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("dt")
                select (string)c.Element("name") + (string)c.Element("email");
        foreach (string item in t)
        {                   
               listView.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

Comment: You say you have some problems but not what those problems are. What's it currently doing, compared with what you want it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("emails.xml");            

var t = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("dt")
select new
{
    Name = e.Element("name").Value,
    EMail = e.Element("email").Value,
};


foreach (var item in t)
{                   
    var lvi = listView.Items.Add(item.Name);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(item.EMail);
}
```

Comment: My problem was that I wasnt sure how to split the parsed values into the seperate columns. Your code worked perfectly, thanks.